# is there an IF formula to read multi function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns and one of them in remark the 3rd one, my first column is status which is (CLOSED & OPEN) and second column is target date, now my question is how is it possible to read the 1st column and 2nd column in my remarks as "Reminder, Over Due, And DONE" if its CLOSED?

I tried this formula:

`=IF(AG18>TODAY(),"Over Due",IF(AND(D18="CLOSED","OPEN",D18,"DONE",""),"Reminder","Done"))`

It works but the 1st column is not shown.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean by "the 1st column is not shown."  Could you show an example of a few rows and what the expected outcome is, please?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you want to do but you are near enough to a solution on your own that a little help will get you there.
The first question, I believe, is about the Status. So, this is your basic formula:

```
=IF(AG18 = "Open", True, False)
```

Obviously, if the propject isn't "open" it must be closed and, I think, if the project is closed there is no more need for action. Therefore replace the the False in the above formula with "Done".

```
=IF(AG18 = "Open", True, "Done")
```

Now, what is to be done if the project is still Open? I think you want to look at the date. Perhaps like this:-

```
IF(AH18 < TODAY(), True, False)
```

It would seem that if the date is smaller than Today, meaning it is in the past, the project must be overdue. Therefore:-

```
IF(AH18 < TODAY(), "Overdue", False)
```

But if the date is equal to you may wish to remind and if it is still in the future you may want to do nothing. That is yet another IF statement which would look as follows.

```
IF(AH18 = TODAY(), "Reminder", "OK")
```

Now, the last and third IF statement is what you want to have as a False result in the second statement. Therefore we replace the "False" there with the last statement.

```
IF(AH18 < TODAY(), "Overdue", False)
becomes
IF(AH18 < TODAY(), "Overdue", IF(AH18 = TODAY(), "Reminder", "OK"))
```

And, of course, the second IF statement was meant to be the True result for the first one. Hence,

```
 =IF(AG18 = "Open", True, "Done")
becomes
 =IF(AG18 = "Open", IF(AH18 < TODAY(), "Overdue", IF(AH18 = TODAY(), "Reminder", "OK")), "Done")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and support my friend it works so well...

Comment: Glad you figured it out. If my answer contributed, please mark it as "Selected". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 3 columns with headers (column name):
Status (B)
Due Date (C)
Remark (D)

now let's say you will save:
Task Names in Column A
Task Status in Column B (Open or Closed)
Task Due Date in Column C
Remark for the Task in Column D

You want the sheet to show if the task is **Over Due**, **Reminder** or **Done** depending on a particular combination of data in columns B and C

Step 1: Check if the Task status and if Open then check the Due date and then Either should show as Over Due or Reminder, if the task is Closed, it should show as Done

> IF(B2="Closed","Done",IF(OR(B2="",B2=FALSE),"Enter
>   Status",IF(C2=Today(),"Overdue","Reminder")))

Alternately you can use Today()-1 --> Reminder and Today() --> Overdue
In a table like the following:
[Excel sheet image with an assumed column with headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMHb3.png)

and use vlookup with **[range_lookup]** as false to determine the remark:

> IF(B2="Closed","Done",VLOOKUP(C2,H:I,2,TRUE))